# Split date range to multiple rows using MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have these values in a table

```
Emp_ID |Employee_Name | Start Date | End date 
---------------------------------
A0001  |Adam          |25-03-2018  | 31-03-2018
B0052  |Brad          |28-04-2018  | 30-04-2018
```

I want to write a select statement that should give me results like:

```
Emp_ID |Employee_Name |  Date | 
---------------------------------
A0001  |Adam          |25-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |26-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |27-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |28-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |29-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |30-03-2018 
A0001  |Adam          |31-03-2018 
B0052  |Brad          |28-04-2018 
B0052  |Brad          |29-04-2018 
B0052  |Brad          |30-04-2018
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

Have a separate table "Index" that just consists of one column (IndexNum) of sequential numbers (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.... as many rows as you need for the maximum possible range of dates, I keep a very large table with positive and negative numbers as both can be useful).

Create a new query that is a Cartesian join between the Index table and your employee table.  That is, both tables are added all on their own with no links between them.

If you select Employee ID, Name and Start Date columns from the Employee table, and the IndexNum column from the Index table you will get all possible combinations - or a row for each employee for each row in the index table.  Now, just limit which Index columns get returned - put a where clause on the IndexNum so that you only get Index rows that are less than the number of days different between End Date and Start Date.

Pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT 
     tbl_Empl.*, tbl_Empl.[Start Date] + IndexNum AS Date 
FROM [Actual Name of Your Employees Table] AS tbl_Empl, 
     [Actual Name of Your Index Table] as tbl_Index 
WHERE 
     tbl_Index.IndexNum >= 0 AND tbl_Index.IndexNum <= (tbl_Empl.[End Date]-tbl_Empl.[Start Date])
```

You will need to play around with substituting your actual table names, and if you have time stamps in the Date fields it can get a little tricky.

Comment: it Works perfectly , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, create a separate table of *Dates* that encompasses a range for all employees (such as 01/01/2018 - 31/12/2018). Then run a cross join filter query:

```
SELECT e.[Emp_ID], e.Employee_Name, d.[RangeDate] As [Date]
FROM Employees e, DatesTable d
WHERE d.[RangeDate] BETWEEN e.[Start Date] AND e.[End Date]
ORDER BY e.[Emp_ID], d.[RangeDate]
```

Here's a way to build such a dates table in MS Access VBA (using parameterization) after creating a *DatesTable* of one column, *DateRange*:

```vb
Sub RunDatesLoop()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim qdef As QueryDef
    Dim i As Long

    ' PREPARED STATEMENT
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS DateParam Date;" _
               & " INSERT INTO DatesTable (RangeDate) VALUES ([DateParam])"

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    For i = 0 To 364
        ' BIND VALUES TO PARAMS AND EXECUTE
        qdef!DateParam = DateAdd("d", i, CDate("01/01/2018"))
        qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
    Next i

    Set qdef = Nothing
    MsgBox "Successfully completed!", vbInformation
End Sub
```